# jquery: help difference between domready and $(function…

Tags: jquery, domready

hey guys,
i found a very intersting website template that has in it's header file the following lines:

```
(function($){
 $(function(){

…normal jquery

 }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

what does that mean? i thought if i want to use domready i hav to write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

where is the difference and can i change that?
thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(function() {` is a just [a shortcut](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) for `$(document).ready(function() {`, they are equivalent.  The `(function($){` .... `})(jQuery);` portion is just for compatibility, so that `$` is the `jQuery` object inside the scope (even if it's something else outside).

Something to note here: `document.ready` handlers receive `jQuery` as their first argument, so the site's code could be more concisely expressed as:

```
jQuery(function($){
  …normal jquery
}); // end of document ready
```

So the answer your question: do you have to change it? nope, use whichever format you prefer...I prefer `$(function() { });` because it's less to type and I do it a hundred times a day.  If you find `$(document).ready(function() { });` much clearer, stick with that, but they behave the same...so use whichever is clearer to you and your team.

Comment: think you have a typo Nick; should s/#/$/ there

Comment: @p00ya - not following, where at?

Answer (score 1):

The DOM ready portion of the code you cited:

```
$(function() {
  // Document is ready let's write some jQuery!
});
```

Is entirely equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // Document is ready let's write some jQuery!  
});
```

The part that wraps the DOM ready stuff is there for a completely separate purpose:

```
(function($) {
  ...
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery namespace
```

The above is actually a function invocation.  You're calling an anonymous function and passing in the `jQuery` object as an argument, which is then assigned to the parameter `$`.  This ensures that all of the code inside (where I've got `...`) can use `$` knowing that it refers to `jQuery`.

This is a failsafe that people use because some other JavaScript code could have assigned the `$` variable to something other than `jQuery` within the global namspace.  By wrapping your jQuery code in a function (remember -- only functions have scope in JavaScript) that assigns `jQuery` to `$`, you're safe.